# Slow drawing on graphical device

Tags: r, dictionary, rgdal

I am using R to do some map plotting through rgdal. I am using one base map and then I'm making a number (approx 30) of different maps with some tracks on the base map.

If I open the basemap in e.g. qgis, they render instatiniously, but R needs about 30 secs on rendering a base map. Since I am using the same base map all the time, is it possible to set it up once and then copy it for the other maps?

I tried to do

```
plot(basemap)
dev.copy(device=x11)
```

which gave me a new device with the basemap, but during the copy, the map was redrawn, so I used as much time on that... Any other ways of copying a graphical device in R?

Comment: Are you drawing a lot of points or polygons?

Comment: The base map is a polygon map with about 400 polygons, so I would not say it is a very large map- (fetched from postgis, but I fetch it once and store it as a variable)

Comment: 30 seconds is a bit much. Can you whip up an example that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: If the polygons have a lot of vertices I can see this being an issue. 30 seconds is a long time, but I often wait many seconds for a map of the UK to render in a base graphics window (for me on Linux with the default graphics device) - it is from a shapefile import and has quite a convoluted coastline.

Comment: I will add, it is much quicker drawing to a `pdf()` device for example. Which is what I do.

Comment: Roman: It is a bit hard to come up with an example, since I am pulling the map out of a postgis database of approx 1G ... (I could maybe save just that map as a shapefile somewhere )

Comment: Gavin: Yes, it is possible it a lot of vertices - but thanks for the pdf-tip, What I do with the map is to export it to pdf ...